# How to read nested arrays and maps in Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read nested array and maps in android studio (Java) from firestore but could not able to iterate through it. I am new to it so can anyone please help me. Thank you :)

Edited: How can I iterate through "options" as it is an array in map.
I've achieved the rest by saving them in HashMap and iterating through it.

[image]

Comment: You can do with a loop inside a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Can you please show me how can i do it?  and with foreach or just for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a data class for your JSON. You can do it with [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-)
Let's say you have something like that (this example done in kotlin):

```
data class Data(
    val id: Int,
    val lists: List<Company>,
    val name: String
)

data class Company(
    val q: String,
    val type: String,
    val optType: Int?,
    val data: List<Options>?
)

data class Options(
    val option : String
)
```

After that, you can do a loop following

```
 for (Company list : data.getLists()) { // data is your object. GetList returns first array
            for (Options datum : list.getData()) { // from list you will get next array.
                System.out.println(datum.getOption()); // here you will get item from nested array
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'll try this solution in android studio java